# undefined reference to my function in code blocks (c and c++)

Tags: codeblocks, undefined-reference

I am making a project in code blocks and c c++. 
for that I need to create multiple files for storing multiple functions...I created a .h file for prototype  and a .c file for implementation....when I include a .h file in my main. cpp file...an error message says that undefined reference to the function that I created..what should I do? I used .c for implementation and .cpp for my main. Is that a problem? I tried creating both prototype and implementation in .h file. but it clutters the file

Comment: I also tried extern keyword..but I got no solution.

Comment: Which is it, c or c++.  You can't have both.

Comment: Half an hour gone and no replies

Comment: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/362365/linking-header-files-in-codeblocks

Comment: You can't link C with C++ object files via shared headers without taking special measures in the code. They are different languages. You are very unlikely to get answer to your problem unless you post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)